# Meteor collection2 field in $unset list

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2

I have a simpleSchema:

```
  imageUrl: {
    type: Object,
    optional: true,
    autoValue: function() {
      if (Meteor.isClient) return;
      var imageField = this.field('imageId');
      if (!imageField.isSet){
        this.unset();
      } else {
        var imageObj = MealsImages.findOne(imageField.value);
        if (imageObj){
          return {thumb: imageObj.S3Url('thumb'), big: imageObj.S3Url('big')};
        }
      }
    },
    autoform: {
      label: false,
      type: 'hidden',
      afFieldInput: {
        type: "hidden"
      }
    }
  },
```

For some reason, when I update the record this field always appears in $unset array:

```
Meteor.methods({
  mealUpsert: function(doc, mealId) {
    check(doc, Meals.simpleSchema());

    console.log('test7');
    console.log(doc);

    if (mealId){
      Meals.update({_id: mealId}, doc);
    } else {
      mealId = Meals.insert(doc);
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

Will print:

```
I20150830-21:49:39.560(-4)? { '$set': 
...
I20150830-21:49:39.562(-4)?   '$unset': 
I20150830-21:49:39.562(-4)?    { imageUrl: '',
...
```

I'm using autoform:

```
<template name="mealUpdateForm">
  <div class="meal-content">
    {{> quickForm collection="Meals" doc=this id="mealUpdateForm" meteormethod="mealUpsert" type="method-update"}}
  </div>
</template>
```

And will never be updated or set. Any clue why field could appear in `$unset` list?

Comment: You need to show the code which creates the doc that gets passed to your method.

Comment: I use autoform, the code is automatically created by it. So it may be the issue of autoform too. Will update description.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured this out - you have a `this.unset()` in your `autoValue` for *imageUrl*. This is called whenever you omit *imageId* from the modifier, even if it is already present in a document you are modifying!

Comment: ```this.unset()``` I only run if ```!imageField.isSet``` condition is passed. Which is not a case. I already debugged this. Any other clue?